# What is the Correct Way to Dispose a WCF Proxy?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, dispose, nettcpbinding, realproxy

I have been struggling with WCF Proxies. What is the correct way to Dispose a WCF Proxy? The answer is not trivial.

**System.ServiceModel.ClientBase violates Microsoft's own Dispose-pattern**

`System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>` *does* implement `IDisposable` so one must assume that it should be disposed or used in a `using`-block. These are best practices for anything disposable. The implementation is explicit, however, so one does have to explicitly cast `ClientBase` instances to `IDisposable`, clouding the issue.

The biggest source of confusion, however, is that calling `Dispose()` on `ClientBase` instances that faulted, *even channels that faulted because they never opened in the first place*, will result in an exception being thrown. This, inevitably, means that the meaningful exception explaining the fault is immediately lost when the stack unwinds, the `using` scope ends and `Dispose()` throws a meaningless exception saying that you can't dispose a faulted channel.

The above behaviour is anathema to the *dispose* pattern which states that objects must be tolerant of multiple explicit calls to `Dispose()`. (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx, "*...allow the `Dispose(bool)` method to be called more than once. The method might choose to do nothing after the first call.*")

With the advent of *inversion-of-control*, this poor implementation becomes a real problem. I.O.C. containers (specifically, Ninject) detect the `IDisposable` interface and call `Dispose()` explicitly on activated instances at the end of an injection scope.

**Solution: Proxy ClientBase and Intercept calls to Dispose()**

My solution was to proxy `ClientBase` by subclassing `System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy` and to hijack or intercept calls to `Dispose()`. My first replacement for `Dispose()` went something like this:

```
if (_client.State == CommunicationState.Faulted) _client.Abort();
else ((IDisposable)_client).Dispose();
```

(Note that `_client` is a typed reference to the target of the proxy.)

**Problems with NetTcpBinding**

I thought that this had nailed it, initially, but then I discovered a problem in production: under certain scenarios that were fiendishly difficult to reproduce, I found that channels using a `NetTcpBinding` were not closing properly in the unfaulted case, even though `Dispose` was being called on `_client`.

I had an ASP.NET MVC Application using my proxy implementation to connect to a WCF Service using a `NetTcpBinding` on the local network, hosted within a Windows NT Service on a service cluster with only one node. When I load-tested the MVC Application, certain endpoints on the WCF Service (which was using port-sharing) would stop responding after a while.

I struggled to reproduce this: the same components running across the LAN between two developer's machines worked perfectly; a console application hammering the real WCF endpoints (running on the staging service cluster) with many processes and many threads in each worked; configuring the MVC Application on the staging server to connect to the endpoints on a developer's machine worked under load; running the MVC Application on a developer's machine and connecting to the staging WCF endpoints worked. The last scenario only worked under IIS Express, however, and this was a breakthrough. The endpoints would sieze up when load-testing the MVC Application under full-fat IIS on a developer's machine, connecting to the staging service cluster.

**Solution: Close the Channel**

After failing to understand the problem and reading many, many pages of the MSDN and other sources that claimed the problem shouldn't exist at all, I tried a long-shot and changed my `Dispose()` work-around to...

```
if (_client.State == CommunicationState.Faulted) _client.Abort();
else if (_client.State == CommunicationState.Opened)
{
    ((IContextChannel)_client.Channel).Close();
    ((IDisposable)_client).Dispose();
}
else ((IDisposable)_client).Dispose();
```

... and the problem stopped occurring in all test setups and under load in the staging environment!

**Why?**

Can anyone explain what might have been happening and why explicitly closing the `Channel` before calling `Dispose()` solved it? As far as I can tell, this shouldn't be necessary.

Finally, I return to the opening question: What is the correct way to Dispose a WCF Proxy? Is my replacement for `Dispose()` adequate?

Answer (score 1):

The issue, as far as I have been able to understand, is that calling `Dispose` disposes off the handle, but doesn't actually close the channel, which then holds on to the resources and then eventually times out.

This is why your service stopped responding after a while during load testing: because the initial calls held on to resources longer than you thought they would, and later calls could then not avail those resources.

I came up with the following solution. The premise of the solution is that calling `Dispose` should be enough to dispose off the handle as well as close the channel. The additional benefit is that if the client ends up in a faulted state, it is recreated so that subsequent calls succeed.

If `ServiceClient<TService>` is injected into another class via a dependency injection framework like `Ninject`, then all resources will properly be released.

NB: Please note that in the case of `Ninject`, the binding must define a scope, i.e., it must not be missing an `InXyzScope` or be defined with an `InTransientScope`. If no scope makes sense, then use `InCallScope`.

Here's what I came up with:

```
public class ServiceClient<TService> : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ChannelFactory<TService> channelFactory;

    private readonly Func<TService> createChannel;

    private Lazy<TService> service;

    public ServiceClient(ChannelFactory<TService> channelFactory)
        : base()
    {
        this.channelFactory = channelFactory;

        this.createChannel = () =>
        {
            var channel = ChannelFactory.CreateChannel();

            return channel;
        };

        this.service = new Lazy<TService>(() => CreateChannel());
    }

    protected ChannelFactory<TService> ChannelFactory
    {
        get
        {
            return this.channelFactory;
        }
    }

    protected Func<TService, bool> IsChannelFaulted
    {
        get
        {
            return (service) =>
                {
                    var channel = service as ICommunicationObject;

                    if (channel == null)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    return channel.State == CommunicationState.Faulted;
                };
        }
    }

    protected Func<TService> CreateChannel
    {
        get
        {
            return this.createChannel;
        }
    }

    protected Action<TService> DisposeChannel
    {
        get
        {
            return (service) =>
                {
                    var channel = service as ICommunicationObject;

                    if (channel != null)
                    {
                        switch (channel.State)
                        {
                            case CommunicationState.Faulted:
                                channel.Abort();
                                break;

                            case CommunicationState.Closed:
                                break;

                            default:
                                try
                                {
                                    channel.Close();
                                }
                                catch (CommunicationException)
                                {
                                }
                                catch (TimeoutException)
                                {
                                }
                                finally
                                {
                                    if (channel.State != CommunicationState.Closed)
                                    {
                                        channel.Abort();
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                };
        }
    }

    protected Action<ChannelFactory<TService>> DisposeChannelFactory
    {
        get
        {
            return (channelFactory) =>
                {
                    var disposable = channelFactory as IDisposable;

                    if (disposable != null)
                    {
                        disposable.Dispose();
                    }
                };
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        DisposeChannel(this.service.Value);
        DisposeChannelFactory(this.channelFactory);
    }

    public TService Service
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.service.IsValueCreated && IsChannelFaulted(this.service.Value))
            {
                DisposeChannel(this.service.Value);

                this.service = new Lazy<TService>(() => CreateChannel());
            }

            return this.service.Value;
        }
    }
}
```